# Aligning text in center in a fixed width div with an image

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` containing an image and some text. The image is supposed to come at the left corner and the text is supposed to come in the center of the `<div>`. But the text is coming off a little off-center to the right due to the width of the image. 
How do i fix it??

```
<header>
<img id="searchBoxProp" src="/resources/images/searchBoxProp.png">
<div class="title">RECIPE SEARCH</div>
</header>


header #searchBoxProp { margin: -16px 0 0 2px; width: 43px; float: left; }
header .title { text-align: center; margin-left: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `header` to `position:relative`, and `#searchBoxProp` to `position:absolute`. Absolute positioning takes the element out of the layout, so it won't affect the text postion. The relative positioning on header makes sure that `#searchBoxProp` is positioned relatively to `header`, instead of the browser window.

```
header {
    position:relative;
}
#searchBoxProp {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px; /* set to your needs */
    top:0px; /* set to your needs */
}
```

Comment: It is better to set too 100% width and then center your text so you dont have define left, and it will change automatically if parent container is changed.

Comment: @DominicGreen OP mentioned that the image had to be in `left corner` - so I presume it's an icon he wants in top left position - not a full width background.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the image as background of the `<div class="title">` and then set `text-align:center` in order to align the text properly.

The HTML could be just:

```
<header>
   <div class="title">RECIPE SEARCH</div>
</header>
```

And the CSS:

```
div.title { 
   background-image:url('/resources/images/searchBoxProp.png');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   text-align:center;
}
```

You will also need to set a fixed height (equal to the image), and finally set the width you wish.

Comment: +1 should have thought of that myself :-) since the image needs to be in the top left corner of header, i'd set the background on header instead, and add no-repeat + position...

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that. Thanks :)

Comment: Allways happy when some one decided to use background rather than arguing :)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use a background image however if not you can use position absolue like this.

```
header{position:relative;}
header .title { position:absolute; width:100%; display:block; text-align:center; }
```